# For what reasons it is not preferable to use Thrift API for Cassandra access?

Tags: cassandra, thrift

Please enumerate reasons for why its not advisable to use Thrift interface for Cassandra? What are the possible advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the raw Thrift apis the cons will be:

- no connection pooling
- no monitoring
- no object oriented interface (not entirely true)
- no failover support

Answer (score 3):

To continue Schildmeijer's good start:

- No batch interface.
- No chunking of get_range_slices() or get_indexed_slices() so you can easily swamp Cassandra
- Non-string types must be packed into binary strings yourself
- You'll probably mess up timestamp precision
- Exception messages are generally useless
- Thrift is broken by default in some languages.  See the PHP C extension, for example.
- Because the code is generated, it's not intuitive, especially regarding super columns, SlicePredicates and batch_mutate().
- Schema modification commands don't wait for schema agreement among all the nodes in the cluster